# Restore System Paths and Permissions

Tags: linux, centos, permissions

I mistakenly ran a command in "root" which I was supposed to run within an account, but forgot to switch before running it so the whole system paths have been messed up and all websites are throwing 403 Error. I need suggestions to restore the system paths.

Server Info: linux, Centos7

This is the sample of the command I ran initially that caused the problem:

```
chown -R user:user /home/
```

To correct things, I started by running:

```
chown root.root /home
```

Now, I want to go ahead and use the commands below to restore the paths of the individual user accounts, but I'm not sure if that could restore every system path correctly.

- Home directory

  chown -R user:user /home/user/
- Public_html

  chown -R user:user /home/user/public_html
- Mail directories

  /scripts/mailperm user

Is this the right course of action to take to fix the problem without causing any further problem to the server? Any other suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: No, you won't be able to set *everything* back to the way they were without a backup (or something else documenting the way things were). You may be able to set them to reasonable values, but there's no guarantee that's what they were before.

Comment: Thank you for the support. I appreciate that.